# Why all supported architectures are not displayed in archive review?

Tags: ios, xcode

In archive review isn't it supposed to show all the supported architectures?

[image]

My project's supported architectures,

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the instructions in `arm64e` and `armv7s` are a superset of `arm64`. Therefore the app build for `arm64` will work on them too.

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan